# How to get Current Date in Ballerina

Tags: wso2, ballerina

Is there a way to get the current date in ballerina?

Comment: The API docs do contain the usage of the standard library functions. Refer to https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/time.html

Answer (score 2):

As I was browsing through some code examples I came across the syntax to get the current time. Shown below is how to get the current date in Ballerina:

Note: first you have to import the [time package](https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/time.html) given below for this to work.

```
import ballerina/time;
```

Then put the following lines of code:

```
time: Time currentTime = time:[currentTime][2]();
string customTimeString = currentTime.format("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This will give the following output:

```
08-07-2018
```

Answer (score 2):

This is work for ballerina 0.991 and 1.0 first you have to import the time package
Then it will give the current date if you want to get in a format it will included the code

```
import ballerina/time;
```

To get current time

```
time:Time time = time:currentTime();
string standardTimeString = time:toString(time);
io:println("Current system time in ISO format: ", standardTimeString);
```

To format the time

```
string|error customTimeString = time:format(time, "yyyy-MM-dd-E");
if (customTimeString is string) {
    io:println("Current system time in custom format: ", customTimeString);
}
```

y -Years
M -months
d -date
E -day
h -hour
m -Minuit
s -seconds

Answer (score 0):

For `Swan Lake Update 3` they seem to have removed the `time:currentTime()` function.

It seems they have replaced it with `time:utcNow()`.
According to the ballerina [documentation](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/time/latest#:%7E:text=The%20time%3AUtc%20is%20the%20tuple%20representation%20of%20the%20UTC.%20The%20UTC%20represents%20the%20number%20of%20seconds%20from%20a%20specified%20epoch.%20Here%2C%20the%20epoch%20is%20the%20UNIX%20epoch%20of%201970%2D01%2D01T00%3A00%3A00Z.),

"The `time:Utc` is the tuple representation of the UTC. The UTC represents the number of seconds from a specified epoch. Here, the epoch is the UNIX epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z."

So you can convert this above tuple representation to  RFC 3339 timestamp by using,

```
time:Utc currTime = time:utcNow();
string date = time:utcToString(currTime);
io:println(date);
```

Then you will get a result like below,

```
2023-01-14T17:04:15.639510400Z
```

Using ballerina `time` library you can convert to other different representations as well.